# how to fix in python bs4 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am doing scraping with `butifulsoup module` in python

My Code:

```
for cactus in cactus_product:
    price = cactus.find("span", class_="._89yzn").text
    title = cactus.find("span", class_="._2tW1I").text

    f.write(title + "," + price)
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Technicalsmirchis\python_scraping_tutorial\scraper.py", line 24, in <module>
    price = cactus.find('span', class_="_89yzn").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: same is working here: https://youtu.be/vIjXuYRLge8?t=484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `find` function returned None, meaning it did not find the required element.
you can add a `try-except` block in order to check for such exceptions or a `if x is not None:`